# searching sorted items into a sorted sequence

Tags: python, performance, numpy, big-o, binary-search

I want to find a sequence of items in a sorted array of values.
I know that with numpy I can do:

```
l = np.searchsorted(values, items)
```

This has the complexity of O(len(items)*log(len(values))).
However, my items are also sorted, so I can do it in O(len(items)+len(values)) doing:

```
l = np.zeros(items.size, dtype=np.int32)
k, K = 0, len(values)
for i in range(len(items)):
    while k < K and values[k] < items[i]:
        k += 1
    l[i] = k
```

The problem is that this version in pure python is way slower than searchsorted because of the python loop, even for large len(items) and len(values) (~10^6).

Any idea how to "vectorize" this loop with numpy?

Comment: Can't you use `searchsorted` for each item in items while slicing values from the last found index to the end? Perhaps that would speed it up.

Comment: would your method work correctly if an items[i] didn't exist in values? I think it would indicate the first value larger than items[i]

Comment: even if you vectorize it you will still be in python land ... and numpy will blow you out of the water

Comment: @Marek it's the expected behaviour of searchsorted.

Comment: @JoranBeasley by "vectorize" I mean using numpy primitive.

Comment: @PeterE not that much: the time is really spend mainly iterating the python loop.

Comment: this seems like premature optimization to me ... searchsorted is likely "fast enough" as is tbh

Comment: The method that @PeterE is suggesting is already built into numpy 1.9, [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4244) is the relevant PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some example data:

```
# some example data
np.random.seed(0)
n_values = 1000000
n_items = 100000
values = np.random.rand(n_values)
items = np.random.rand(n_items)
values.sort()
items.sort()
```

Your original code snippet as well as an implementation of @PeterE's suggestion:

```
def original(values, items):
    l = np.empty(items.size, dtype=np.int32)
    k, K = 0, len(values)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        while k < K and values[k] < item:
            k += 1
        l[i] = k
    return l

def peter_e(values, items):
    l = np.empty(items.size, dtype=np.int32)
    last_idx = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        last_idx += values[last_idx:].searchsorted(item)
        l[i] = last_idx
    return l
```

Test for correctness against naive `np.searchsorted`:

```
ss = values.searchsorted(items)

print(all(original(values, items) == ss))
# True

print(all(peter_e(values, items) == ss))
# True
```

Timings:

```
In [1]: %timeit original(values, items)
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit peter_e(values, items)
10 loops, best of 3: 79.8 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit values.searchsorted(items)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.09 ms per loop
```

So for inputs of this size, naive use of `np.searchsorted` handily beats your original code, as well as PeterE's suggestion.

### Update

To avoid any caching effects that might skew the timings, we can generate a new set of random input arrays for each iteration of the benchmark:

```
In [1]: %%timeit values = np.random.randn(n_values); items = np.random.randn(n_items); values.sort(); items.sort();
original(values, items)
   .....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop

In [2]: %%timeit values = np.random.randn(n_values); items = np.random.randn(n_items); values.sort(); items.sort();
peter_e(values, items)
   .....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 79.9 ms per loop

In [3]: %%timeit values = np.random.randn(n_values); items = np.random.randn(n_items); values.sort(); items.sort();
values.searchsorted(items)
   .....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 ms per loop
```

### Update 2

It's not that hard to write a Cython function that will beat `np.searchsorted` for the case where both `values` and `items` are sorted.

`search_doubly_sorted.pyx`:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def search_doubly_sorted(values, items):

    cdef:
        double[:] _values = values.astype(np.double)
        double[:] _items = items.astype(np.double)
        long n_items = items.shape[0]
        long n_values = values.shape[0]
        long[:] out = np.empty(n_items, dtype=np.int64)
        long ii, jj, last_idx

    last_idx = 0
    for ii in range(n_items):
        for jj in range(last_idx, n_values):
             if _items[ii] <= _values[jj]:
                break
        last_idx = jj
        out[ii] = last_idx

    return out.base
```

Test for correctness:

```
In [1]: from search_doubly_sorted import search_doubly_sorted

In [2]: print(all(search_doubly_sorted(values, items) == values.searchsorted(items)))                     
# True
```

Benchmark:

```
In [3]: %timeit values.searchsorted(items)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.07 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit search_doubly_sorted(values, items)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

The performance improvement is fairly marginal, though. Unless this is a serious bottleneck in your code then you should probably stick with `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `l[i] = l[i-1] + values[l[i-1]:].searchsorted(item)` ? You have to start slicing at the last found index.

Comment: Also: could you time it (and perhaps validate) against simply using `values.searchsort(items)`?

Comment: thanks for those timings, but I think that to see a significant difference, the size of the arrays should really be larger (and then the np.searchsorted baseline is really fast). My problem is really that the python overhead (hidden in the constant factor of the big-o) is really large.

Comment: @PeterE My version works out as equivalent as long as there are no ties, but yours is more robust. I'll update my code.

Comment: also: your version throws the biggest advantage of my idea away ;-) The idea is to search the smallest possible slice of `values`.

Comment: @rndblnch the timings are now updated for much larger inputs. `np.searchsorted` still crushes the other two approaches.

Comment: Yeah, I get similar results, but I'm concerned about the warnings, that might skew the timings.

Comment: @PeterE see my update - caching doesn't seem to have much effect on the timings

Comment: seems like cython is the way to go. I would have loved to have a "pure" numpy solution, but I can not wrap my head around it…

Comment: @rndblnch As I said, the performance improvement from using Cython was still relatively small. If you haven't already, you should definitely profile your code and see whether this operation is really a bottleneck. If it isn't then it's probably not worth bothering with the Cython version.

Comment: I have profiled and it is the bottleneck. I am working with really large arrays, so the big-o complexity is not only theoretical in my case. A cythonized version is really much faster.