# Rolling average with window size an interval of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate a rolling average on some incomplete data. I want to average values in column 2 across windows of size 1.0 of the value in column 1 (miles). I've tried .rolling(), but (from my limited understanding) this only creates windows based on the index, and not on column values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [4.5, 10],
        [4.6, 11],
        [4.8, 9],
        [5.5, 6],
        [5.6, 6],
        [8.1, 10],
        [8.2, 13]
    ])

averages = []
for index in range(len(df)):
    nearby = df.loc[np.abs(df[0] - df.loc[index][0]) <= 0.5]
    averages.append(nearby[1].mean())
df['rollingAve'] = averages
```

Gives the desired output:

```
     0   1  rollingAve
0  4.5  10        10.0
1  4.6  11        10.0
2  4.8   9        10.0
3  5.5   6         6.0
4  5.6   6         6.0
5  8.1  10        11.5
6  8.2  13        11.5
```

But this slows down substantially for big dataframes. Is there a way to implement .rolling() with varying window sizes, or something similar?

Comment: Your code does not seem to be properly aligned

Comment: @piterbarg thanks, i've fixed it so it should run now

Answer (score 2):

Panda's [BaseIndexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer.html) is quite handy, although it takes a little bit of head-scratching to get it right.

In the following, I use [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to quickly find the indices (start, end) of each window:

```
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class RangeWindow(BaseIndexer):
    def __init__(self, val, width):
        self.val = val.values
        self.width = width

    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
        if min_periods is None: min_periods = 0
        if closed is None: closed = 'left'
        w = (-self.width/2, self.width/2) if center else (0, self.width)
        side0 = 'left' if closed in ['left', 'both'] else 'right'
        side1 = 'right' if closed in ['right', 'both'] else 'left'
        ix0 = np.searchsorted(self.val, self.val + w[0], side=side0)
        ix1 = np.searchsorted(self.val, self.val + w[1], side=side1)
        ix1 = np.maximum(ix1, ix0 + min_periods)

        return ix0, ix1
```

Some deluxe options: `min_periods`, `center`, and `closed` are implemented according to what the [DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) specifies.

**Application:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [4.5, 10],
        [4.6, 11],
        [4.8, 9],
        [5.5, 6],
        [5.6, 6],
        [8.1, 10],
        [8.2, 13]
    ], columns='a b'.split())

df.b.rolling(RangeWindow(df.a, width=1.0), center=True, closed='both').mean()

# gives:
0    10.0
1    10.0
2    10.0
3     6.0
4     6.0
5    11.5
6    11.5
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

**Timing:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.uniform(0, 1000, size=(1_000_000, 2)),
    columns='a b'.split(),
)
df = df.sort_values('a').reset_index(drop=True)


%%time
avg = df.b.rolling(RangeWindow(df.a, width=1.0)).mean()

CPU times: user 133 ms, sys: 3.58 ms, total: 136 ms
Wall time: 135 ms
```

**Update on performance:**

Following a comment from @anon01, I was wondering if one could go faster for the case when the rolling involves large windows. Turns out I should have measured Pandas's rolling mean and sum performance first... (Premature optimization, anyone?)  See at the end why.

Anyway, the idea was to do a `cumsum` just once, then take the difference of elements dereferenced by the windows endpoints:

```
# both below working on numpy arrays:
def fast_rolling_sum(a, b, width):
    z = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(b)))
    ix0 = np.searchsorted(a, a - width/2, side='left')
    ix1 = np.searchsorted(a, a + width/2, side='right')
    return z[ix1] - z[ix0]

def fast_rolling_mean(a, b, width):
    z = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(b)))
    ix0 = np.searchsorted(a, a - width/2, side='left')
    ix1 = np.searchsorted(a, a + width/2, side='right')
    return (z[ix1] - z[ix0]) / (ix1 - ix0)
```

With this (and the 1-million rows `df` above), I see:

```
%timeit fast_rolling_mean(df.a.values, df.b.values, width=100.0)
# 93.9 ms ± 335 µs per loop
```

versus:

```
%timeit df.rolling(RangeWindow(df.a, width=100.0), min_periods=1).mean()
# 248 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop
```

*However!!!*  Pandas is likely already doing such an optimization (it's a pretty obvious one). The timings don't increase with larger windows (which is why I was saying I should have checked first).

Comment: This is very cool, I didn't know about searchsorted.  Any idea of the performance for a large dataset, or when the window size has many rows?

Comment: This feels like a gap in the pandas API.  I wonder how far out of spec this would be as a contribution

Comment: @anon01 `np.searchsorted` is quite fast (the algorithm is the same as `bisect`), but admittedly it could be faster when the second array is sorted (there should be a flag to tell `numpy` when that's the case). See e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682000/758174) for discussion. That said, on a `r5d.2xlarge` EC2 instance, I see ~540ms for `searchsorted(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are sorted and have 10 millions float64. As for the overall operation in my answer above: there is no additional cost for dealing with large windows (I initially thought like you but that's not the case)

Answer (score 0):

`df.rolling` and `series.rolling` do allow for value-based windows if the index is of type `DateTimeIndex` or `TimedeltaIndex`.  You can use this to get close to the desired result:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.TimedeltaIndex(df[0]*1e9))
df["rolling_mean"] = df[1].rolling("1s").mean()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
     0   1  rolling_mean
0  4.5  10     10.000000
1  4.6  11     10.500000
2  4.8   9     10.000000
3  5.5   6      8.666667
4  5.6   6      7.000000
5  8.1  10     10.000000
6  8.2  13     11.500000
```

**Advantages**
This is a three-line solution that should have great performance, leveraging pandas datetime backend.

**Disadvantages**
This is definitely a hack, casting your miles column to time-delta seconds, and the average isn't centered (`center` isn't implemented for datetimelike and offset based windows).

Overall: if you value performance and can live with a non-centered mean, this would be a great way to go with a comment or two.