# Pandas: Count user instances in a adaptive date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

The problem: Let's say there's a historical record of user interactions, that has `USER_ID` and `TIME` of the interaction. I am trying to create several columns that would have the count of, let's say, `LAST_YEAR` interactions since the current interaction

EXAMPLE INPUT:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':   [1,1,1,5,1],
    'TIME': ['2019-12-01','2019-11-01','2019-10-01','2019-10-01','2019-10-10']
})
df_in 
#   ID  TIME
# 0 1   2019-12-01
# 1 1   2019-11-01
# 2 1   2019-10-01
# 3 5   2019-10-01
# 4 1   2019-10-10
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':   [1,1,1,5,1],
    'TIME': ['2019-12-01','2019-11-01','2019-10-01','2019-10-01','2019-10-10'],
    'LAST_YEAR': [4,3,2,1,1],
    'LAST_MONTH': [1,1,2,1,1],
    'LAST_WEEK': [1,1,1,1,1]
})
df_out  

#       ID      TIME    LAST_YEAR   LAST_MONTH  LAST_WEEK
#    0  1   2019-12-01     4            1           1
#    1  1   2019-11-01     3            1           1
#    2  1   2019-10-01     2            2           1
#    3  5   2019-10-01     1            1           1
#    4  1   2019-10-10     1            1           1
```

MY CODE:

```
def df_group_and_slice(df_in, date_from, column_name):
    selection = (df_in['TIME'] > date_from)
    return (df_in[selection].groupby(by=['ID']).size().to_frame(name = column_name))
df_in['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df_in['TIME'])
dates = df_in['TIME'].unique()
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
for date_to in dates:
    df_in_sub = df_in[df_in['TIME']<=date_to]
    year_ago = date + relativedelta(years=-1)
    last_year_calls = df_group_and_slice(df_in_sub, year_ago, 'LAST_YEAR')
    print(date)
    print(last_year_calls)
    print('\n')
```

CODE PRINTS:

```
2019-12-01 00:00:00
    LAST_YEAR
ID           
1           4
5           1


2019-11-01 00:00:00
    LAST_YEAR
ID           
1           3
5           1


2019-10-01 00:00:00
    LAST_YEAR
ID           
1           1
5           1


2019-10-10 00:00:00
    LAST_YEAR
ID           
1           2
5           1
```

with the code above I do get the count of calls as intended, but I am yet to figure out how to join it back together with df_in to get the expected output. Also, I believe that there must be a more pythonic way to do this than using a for loop that I have not found yet.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are okay approximating 'year' and 'month' with fixed frequencies instead (`'365D'` and `'30D'`, respectively), then you can use a `groupby`-`rolling` combo ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#window-and-resample-operations)) and say:

```
out = pd.concat([
    df.groupby('ID').rolling(freq)['ID'].count()
    for freq in ['365D', '30D', '7D']
], keys='LAST_YEAR LAST_MONTH LAST_WEEK'.split(), axis=1)
```

Out:

```
               LAST_YEAR  LAST_MONTH  LAST_WEEK
ID TIME                                        
1  2019-10-01        1.0         1.0        1.0
   2019-10-10        2.0         2.0        1.0
   2019-11-01        3.0         2.0        1.0
   2019-12-01        4.0         1.0        1.0
5  2019-10-01        1.0         1.0        1.0
```

Note: This requires some proper preliminary setup of your `df`, though, such as setting the `'TIME'` to be a `TimeStamp` (instead of a string like in your example data), to be sorted and used as an index (for ease of use). So, for your example:

```
df = df_in.assign(TIME=pd.to_datetime(df_in['TIME'])).set_index('TIME').sort_index()
```

Comment: Well... That's better than what I have, it's easy to read and it solves the problem. Answer accepted! Even though I would be interested in seeing a solution without fixed frequencies. Also... damn, I had never heard of `rolling`. Thank you, sir!

Comment: non-fixed frequencies are trickier to handle (at least with the current version of Pandas), but it is possible to implement your own window function by extending `BaseIndexer`. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64723729/758174). Haven't tested on `RollingGroupBy` though.